# FLV body length

Tags: c#, audio, stream, bit-manipulation, flv

I am making my own FLV audio downloader without using external libraries.
I am following this documentation:

http://osflash.org/flv

In FLV tag type, there are three interesting values:

*BodyLength*, *Timestamp*, *StreamId* which are of `uint24_be` type. How to read them?
I found the answer here:

[Extract Audio from FLV stream in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693656/extract-audio-from-flv-stream-in-c-sharp)

However I don't understand few things:

If *Timestamp* and *StreamId* are both `uint24_be`(also what is `uint24_be`?) then why

```
reader.ReadInt32(); //skip timestamps 
ReadNext3Bytes(reader); // skip streamID
```

Also what exactly `ReadNext3Bytes` do? Why not to read 3 next bytes like this:

```
reader.ReadInt32()+reader.ReadInt32()+reader.ReadInt32();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `reader.ReadInt32()+reader.ReadInt32()+reader.ReadInt32()` because, at first it is 12 bytes instead of 3 bytes, and at second it is not enough simple summarize these bytes - you should make an 24-bit value. Here is more readable version of `ReadNext3Bytes` function:

```
int ReadNext3Bytes(System.IO.BinaryReader reader) {
    try {
        byte b0 = reader.ReadByte();
        byte b1 = reader.ReadByte();
        byte b2 = reader.ReadByte();
        return MakeInt(b0, b1, b2);
    }
    catch { return 0; }
}
int MakeInt(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2) {
    return ((b0 << 0x10) | (b1 << 0x08)) | b2;
}
```