# is possible to extract flv, mp3 .. etc. c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, download, flv

**is possible to extract flv, mp3 .. etc. c# on a site using windows form c#???**

how can I do if it is possible??

*Thanks in advance for answers*

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693656/extract-audio-from-flv-stream-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: You will need to elaborate a bit, your question is not really clear. Do you wish to find links in the html code and download these? This shouldnt be too hard given, for example, regular expressions. If you want to download the actual live media streams, there are a lot of tools for this, like rtmpdump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - however, don't try using any Windows tools to do it.  Instead, use a wrapper around FFMPEG: 
[Using FFmpeg in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net)

In my testing, FFMPEG is far more useful than Windows Media services and far more reliable.

Comment: +1 I concur. Everyone uses FFmpeg even Gerard Lantau.

Comment: I authored a paper five or six years ago about how to extract thumbnails from videos by using the Windows API.  It was a nightmare; slow, unreliable, would work on some computers but not others; required tons of codec packs... then I replaced it with a call to FFMPEG and all was well.